# Is eating dirt good?

Tags: nutrition, diet, food-safety, food-poisoning, toxins

A while back, I my parents knew a family who had a son. His parents believed in some weird thing that if you eat dirt, your immunity will increase and you will be less prone to sickness. However in my opinion, I think this is a very stupid thing to do, as all sorts of stuff could be in the ground, ranging from garbage to toxins. Aside from that, **is there any benefit to eating dirt? Is it worth it?**

Comment: Researchers have found that children who grow up in a dirty environment are less likely to suffer asthma and allergies than kids who grow up in clean environments. I think there is likely some value to exposing the childhood immune system to a lot of pathogens in small numbers, as would happen from children putting dirty fingers in their mouths, noses, etc. But intentionally eating gobs of dirt? Sounds like a bad idea based on myth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Dr. Sera Young of Cornell University, the most likely of the theories is that eating mud protects the body from pathogens, parasites, and plant toxins. It's suspected to be due to the clay's ability to bind things — perhaps the clay is binding the toxins before they can make you sick. This theory would explain why children and pregnant women are the most common dirt eaters; they are the most susceptible to illness. Clay may even have properties that protect against malaria.

http://abcnews.go.com/Health/Diet/story?id=1167623&page=1